# Spark Scala - how to compare certain element in one row with another element in a different row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a joined RDD of RDD[Int, (String, String),(String, String)]
for example:

```
(1, (UserID1, pwd1),(UserID2, pwd2))
(2, (UserID2, pwd2),(UserID3, pwd3))
(3, (UserID3, pwd3),(UserID4, pwd4))
```

As you can see these 3 rows are chained together by the 3rd placeholder of a given row to the 2nd placeholder of the next row (row 1 and row 2 are linked by (UserID2, pwd2); row 2 and 3 are linked by (UserID3, pwd3).

How to I process the data so that so I can dedupe the common items and get the result as Rdd

```
((UserID1, pwd1),(UserID2, pwd2),(UserID3, pwd3),(UserID4, pwd4))
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved using `flatMap` and then `distinct` .

```
scala> rdd.map(s=>Seq(s._2,s._3)).flatMap(s=>s).distinct.foreach(println(_))
```

output:

```
(UserID4,pwd4)
(UserID2,pwd2)
(UserID3,pwd3)
(UserID1,pwd1)
```